# How to stop scrolling from switching between windows in Unity?

Tags: 16.04, unity, scrolling, application-switcher

I keep accidentally moving my mouse over the launcher while I'm browsing websites and then switching to other windows when I try to scroll. I've never purposefully switched applications this way, and I'd really like to disable it. However, I've searched the settings window, and I don't see an option do so.

How can I disable this behavior?

Comment: +1 for asking as I did not even realize Unity did this and I like it. Now I know how to use it (or disable it if I change my mind!).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Ubuntu 16.04, this is fairly straightforward to disable, even if it isn't intuitive. Simply enter the following command in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ scroll-inactive-icons false
```

If you ever want to re-enable it, just do the opposite:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ scroll-inactive-icons true
```

Comment: This works on 14.04 too.

Comment: does not seem to work any longer on 16.04